# how do i sort this list of emails using bash?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

I'm trying to sort a list of emails using a bash script with  code below but I'm getting the wrong output, advice

`sort  -t @ -k1,1`

Comment: the expected output is 
example.example@example.com,
example45@example.com,
example@example.com  instead i get example@example.com,
example45@example.com,
example.example@example.com

Comment: Please [edit] your question; the comments down here are obviously not very helpful because you can't use proper formatting, and they are likely to be removed anyway.  Also, your question should be self-contained in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to add -d for dictionary order and so:

```
sort -r -d -t@ -k1,1
```

Comment: this gets the correct output but in reverse order the output is now example@example.com,
example45@example.com,
example.example@example.com

Comment: i need . ranked before a number in this case 45

Comment: Add -r to reverse the order

Comment: yeah that works but its only a hack, when other emails are added to the list it doesnt work, how do i make it work wihout -r